# How can I use Java Generic to suppress the warning?

Tags: java, generics

In the code below,
a warning appears while assigning a value to a generic type field in the update method of the Device class.

How do I fix it to get the correct code?

```java
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Device<T> {
        private boolean updated;
        private T value;
        private Date updatedAt;

        public void update(Device<?> p) {
            this.value = (T) p.getValue(); // unchecked case warning
            this.updatedAt = p.getUpdatedAt();
            this.updated = true;
        }
    }
```

```java
    Map<DeviceName, Device<?>> currDevices= getDevices(...);
    Map<DeviceName, Device<?>> newDevices = getNewDevices(...);

    for (DeviceName name : currDevices.keySet()) {
        Device<?> device = currDevices.get(name);
        Device<?> newDevice = newDevices.get(name);

        if (device.getUpdatedAt() == null || device.getUpdatedAt().before(newDevice.getUpdatedAt())) {
            // If I modify the device.update method -> public void update(Device<T> p) {
            // An error occurs here.
            device.update(newDevice);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `p` is declared as `Device<?>`, how do you know it's actually a `T`?

Comment: can you explain why `update` takes a `Device<?>` and not a `Device<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `(T) foo`, where T is a generics type variable, you're making a **type assertion**. As in, that is a literal no-op. That cannot ever throw a `ClassCastException` and doesn't convert anything whatsoever. Nevertheless, it may not be a `T` (you're simply telling the compiler: I'm sure it is, based on nothing other than because I say so), which means someplace else, much later and perhaps a different thread, a `ClassCastException` occurs even though you're not casting anything.

The solution is generally to never use the cast operator when any type var is in the parens.

Here, that's a simple matter: Make that `Device<? extends T> p` instead of `Device<?> p`, easy peasy. It makes sense, presumably: A `Device<Number>` cannot be updated with a `Device<String>`; you'd need a `Device<Number>` or perhaps a `Device<Integer>`.

> `Map<DeviceName, Device<?>> currDevices= getDevices(...);`

This is a so-called heterogenous map; a map that maps `DeviceName` to many different types. Java doesn't like these, and generally that means you're now committed to these warnings. **You cannot get rid of them** without rewriting how this code works entirely. That map needs to go away somehow. Java has absolutely no way to verify that a `currDevices.get("foo")` returns the same kind of Device as `newDevices.get("foo")`.

There are workarounds but nothing universal. You'd have to explain far more detail what `Device` is for, what the `T` represents, what `update` is supposed to do, how your system works, etcetera.

Nevertheless, if you're going to go with this setup where a cast-with-warning is inevitable, at least put the error in the right place, which is *not* by making the signature of `update()` broken, as that's a method signature. Those are important.

Instead, then 'fix' it at call site. Here that would mean making `device` (the local variable)`a raw type (just`Device` - yes, that gets you a warning, that's the point: You can't avoid it without rewriting to not use a heterogenous map). That way the generics issues at least do not show up in method signatures.

Comment: I disagree that any workaround should include a raw type.  Instead look at heterogeneous type safe container.  https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=8

Comment: It's a bit above and beyond basic java, and crucially, passing `Class<T>` around means it doesn't work when T, itself, contains generics, e.g. T is `List<String>`. This is, in effect, an X/Y problem: There is some unstated issue, OP thought they'd solve it with a heterogenous map, and is now asking questions about how to work with HMs. it's possible HM is the best answer _and_ that T is never likely to itself have generics, thus making that link relevant, but that's two _big_ ifs!

Comment: `it doesn't work when T, itself, contains generics` Fair point.  Yes reified generics would help Java a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If we can't eliminate the “unchecked cast” warning and we're sure that the code provoking the warning is typesafe, we can suppress the warning using the SuppressWarnings(“unchecked”) annotation.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Device<T> {
    private boolean updated;
    private T value;
    private Date updatedAt;

    public void update(Device<?> p) {
        SuppressWarnings(“unchecked”) 
        this.value = (T) p.getValue(); // unchecked case warning
        this.updatedAt = p.getUpdatedAt();
        this.updated = true;
    }
}
```

The compiler has to allow this cast to preserve backward compatibility with older Java versions that do not support generics. ClassCastException won't be thrown until we load the data with the wrong type.